# Citrix and Ubuntu Server / Ubuntu Clients for VDI

Tags: ubuntu, xen, citrix, vdi

does anyone have any experience running ubuntu as a hosted desktop using XenServer have any reasons why I should not pursue this option?

Answer (score 0):

I have an Ubuntu server running under XenServer right now.  There are no issues with getting this to work, except for the fact that Citrix does not provide a pre-packaged template for installing Ubuntu under XenServer.

The most simple to do this is to grab the image from here, and do a File->Import from XenServer:

http://www.isaaczarb.com/ubuntu-9-10-x64-template-for-xenserver-5-x/

After you do this, you may want to upgrade ubuntu to the latest version with a do-release-upgrade, you can do that following the instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade

Regards, Port Forward Podcast

http://portforwardpodcast.com/